# Use Azure Runbook to Delete Old Files in Azure file share

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook, storage-file-share

I'm trying the below code to make a runbook, which deletes all file shares that are older than some days. I know that the "LastModified" returns "Null" and it doesn't work the same way as blobs. Instead, one need to use "Get file metadata" and from that get the "LastModified". But I don't know how to get the "Get file metadata" from result of file list.

```
## Declaring the variables
$number_of_days_threshold = 20
$current_date = get-date
$date_before_blobs_to_be_deleted = $current_date.AddDays(-$number_of_days_threshold)

# Number of blobs deleted
$file_count_deleted = 0

# Storage account details
$storage_account_name = "xxx" 
$storage_account_key = "xxx"
$ShareName = "xxx"

## Creating Storage context for Source, destination and log storage accounts
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_account_name -StorageAccountKey $storage_account_key
$file_list = Get-AzureStorageFile -Context $context -ShareName $ShareName
$file_list2 = Get-AzureStorageFileContent -Context $context -ShareName $ShareName

## Creating log file
$log_file = "log-"+(get-date).ToString().Replace('/','-').Replace(' ','-').Replace(':','-') + ".txt"
$local_log_file_path = $env:temp + "\" + "log-"+(get-date).ToString().Replace('/','-').Replace(' ','-').Replace(':','-') + ".txt"

write-host "Log file saved as: " $local_log_file_path -ForegroundColor Green

## Iterate through each blob
foreach($file_iterator in $file_list2){

    $file_date = [datetime]$file_iterator.LastModified.UtcDateTime
    #$file_date = [datetime]$file_iterator.getFileMetadata.LastModified.UtcDateTime
    
    # Check if the blob's last modified date is less than the threshold date for deletion
    if($file_date -le $date_before_files_to_be_deleted) {

        Write-Output "-----------------------------------" | Out-File $local_log_file_path -Append
        write-output "Purging file from Storage: " $file_iterator.name | Out-File $local_log_file_path -Append
        write-output " " | Out-File $local_log_file_path -Append
        write-output "Last Modified Date of the Blob: " $file_date | Out-File $local_log_file_path -Append
        Write-Output "-----------------------------------" | Out-File $local_log_file_path -Append

        # Cmdle to delete the blob
        Remove-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $ShareName -path $file_iterator.Name -Context $context

        $file_count_deleted += 1
    } 

}

write-output "Files deleted: " $file_count_deleted | Out-File $local_log_file_path -Append
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, you can use PowerShell cmdlet `Get-AzureStorageFile` to return files then run the command `$file.FetchAttributes()` to retune your files' properties. These properties contain `LastModified`

For exmaple

```
$share=""
$accountName=""
$key=""
$context =New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $key

#define function to list files in child dir
function listFiles([string]$path){ 
   $file1s=$null
   $file1s=Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $share -Context $context -Path $path | Get-AzureStorageFile  
    foreach($file1 in $file1s){     
      if($file1.GetType().name -eq "CloudFile"){
            $file1.FetchAttributes()
            Write-Output ("Last Modified Date of the file $($file1.Name) is $($file1.Properties.LastModified)") 
       }else{
                   
             listFiles("$($file1.Parent.Name)/$($file1.Name)")
       }

  } 
 
}


#list files in root dir
$files =Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $share -Context $context 


foreach($file in $files){
 if($file.GetType().name -eq "CloudFile"){
     $file.FetchAttributes()
     Write-Output ("Last Modified Date of the file $($file.Name) is $($file.Properties.LastModified)")
 
 }else{
   
     listFiles($file.Name)
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was definitely helpful!
Do you know if such a task is achievable by Azure Cli as well?

Comment: There is an attribute for blob storage, named '--if-unmodified-since', which makes it possible in Cli but there isn't such an attribute for Files.

Comment: @MaryamTavakkoli If you have a new issue, please create a new question in stackoverflow