# Azure storage account fileshare contents retention period

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-storage-account, linux-containers, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have a Linux container web app in Azure.
I have configured the logging path to the Azure storage account file_share path.
Since my application will be dumping more logs and I need to delete the files older than X size or X days.
I can see the option is available in the Storage account for blobs only. 
Is there any way to achieve for file share retention period?

Answer (score 0):

Delete activity can be configured from Azure data Factory / script . You may Refer > [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542455/how-to-remove-azure-file-share-old-data-from-the-azure-storage-account/68576874#68576874) thread where  steps to delete file shares older than 30 days are shown .

Other references:

1. [delete activity- x-days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500637/how-to-delete-from-files-from-azure-file-share-periodically-after-say-x-days)
2. [Using Azure CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046296/use-azure-cli-to-delete-old-files-in-azure-file-share)
3. [Using Runbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028633/use-azure-runbook-to-delete-old-files-in-azure-file-share)